# show an element when another is out of viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

for mobile In vanilla Javascript how to show a "cart" button on the bottom of the page but only when the original "cart" button is out of viewport?

I don't understand how to check when an element goes out of viewport

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header{
    font-size:20px;
}
.sticky{
    background-color: rgb(144, 148, 144);
    padding:10px;
  
    text-align: center;
    position:sticky;
    width:100%;
}

.sticky button{
    padding: 10px;
    width: 80vw;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header class="header">
        Cart
    </header>

  <div class="paraContainer">
    <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
        a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
        remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
        Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
        of Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <div class="sticky">
        <button >
            Add To cart
        </button>
    </div>
  
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Js

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',()=>{
    const scrollable = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight
    const scrolled = window.scrollY;
    if(scrolled === scrollable) {
        console.log('bottom')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick...

change .sticky to..

```
.sticky {
    background-color: rgb(144, 148, 144);
    padding:10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Give sticky an id....

```
<div class="sticky" id="cartDiv">
    <button >
        Add To cart
    </button>
</div>
```

And here is the JS...

```
var cartTop = document.getElementById('cartDiv').getBoundingClientRect().top;

window.addEventListener('scroll',()=>{
    if(window.scrollY > cartTop) {
        console.log('bottom');
        document.getElementById('cartDiv').style.position = 'fixed';
        document.getElementById('cartDiv').style.bottom = '0';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('cartDiv').style.position = 'relative';
        document.getElementById('cartDiv').style.bottom = '';
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wz0mp3nc/1/